# How to convert auto (for vector<string>) from c++11 to c++98?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have this code in C++11:

```
vector<int> stariFinale;

bool LexAnalyzer::eStareFinala(int q)
{
    for (auto x : stariFinale)
        if (q == x)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

And I tried to convert it to C++98 like:

```
bool Analizator_L::eStareFinala(int q)
{
    for (vector<int>::iterator x = stariFinale.begin(); x!= stariFinale.end(); x++)
        if (q == x)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

which gives me the error no match for 'operator==' in 'q==x'

Please, help.

Comment: Including the compiler error message verbatim, rather than paraphrasing, would make the question more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you've got an iterator, not the value, so you must dereference it. And please use prefix ++, not postfix ++. Postfix ++ needs to create a temporary, prefix ++ not, compare the enforcement section of http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rp-waste.

```
for (vector<int>::iterator x = stariFinale.begin(); x != stariFinale.end(); ++x)
    if (q == *x)
        return true;
```

Another option which requires less code changes is to have the iterator and the old x variable:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator iter = stariFinale.begin(); iter != stariFinale.end(); ++iter) {
    int x = *iter;
    if (q == x)
        return true;
}
```

Even better in your case: don't write the loop yourself, use a standard algorithm (compare http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lib). Your function could be implemented by using `std::find`.

```
return std::find(stariFinale.begin(), stariFinale.end(), q) != stariFinale.end();
```

Comment: Although your comments about prefix being preferable to postfix are good, it must be noted that most compilers will pick upon this unused value and factor it out. This is however possibly dependent on your optimization flags.

Comment: @TarickWelling I agree if talking about a builtin type like `int`, but for iterator objects it is much harder for the optimizer to see that because it requires inlining and more. The compiler might optimize in the iterator case, but he might also not optimize.

Answer (score 2):

Like this `if (q == *x)`

Use `*` to get the element that the iterator is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work in C++98 and C++11 or later:

```
bool LexAnalyzer::eStareFinala(int q)
{
    return std::find( stariFinale.begin(), stariFinale.end(), q ) != stariFinale.end();
}
```